# Selecting multiple text() nodes between elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to output the following xml to the browser exactly as it appears below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
  <text>
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <h2>Engineering</h2>
    This is the first bit of text:
      <listofitems>
        <listitem>Database Analysis Tools</listitem>
        <listitem>Website Development</listitem>
        <listitem>Intranet Development</listitem>
        <listitem>Database Development</listitem>
      </listofitems> 
    This is the second piece of text:
      <listofitems>
        <listitem>Hardware</listitem>
        <listitem>Software</listitem>
      </listofitems>
    This is the final piece of text.
  </text>
</content>
```

The problem is with the text strings inside the <text> element - the bits not enclosed in their own tags, i.e. 'This is the first bit of text:', 'This is the second piece of text:' and 'This is the final piece of text.'

I can output all three bits of text in a single block if I use <xsl:value-of select="."/>, but obviously that's not how they appear in the original XML. If I use <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> I get nothing back (I believe text() only references the first child node, which in this case is another element).

I can output the last bit of text with <xsl:value-of select="node()[last()]/self::text()">; I can access each text() node by referencing it directly, e.g. <xsl:value-of select="text()[3]"/>, but as this is meant to be used with random XML which could be of any format I won't be able to reference nodes directly in this way. I tried a for-each on text()[*] but it didn't work. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling around, I think this is close enough to be acceptable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:if test="parent::* or preceding-sibling::*">
        <br/>
    </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$indent" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <!-- open angle brackets -->
      &lt;<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <!-- output any attributes and values -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>="<b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>"
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!-- close angle brackets -->
      &gt;
      <!-- output text content -->
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="indent"><xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <!-- close tag -->
      <xsl:if test="child::*">
        <br/><xsl:value-of select="$indent" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:if>
      &lt;/<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>&gt;  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives this:

```
<content> 
     <text> 
         <h1>Services</h1> 
         <h2>Engineering</h2> This is the first bit of text: 
         <listofitems> 
             <listitem>Database Analysis Tools</listitem> 
             <listitem>Website Development</listitem> 
             <listitem>Intranet Development</listitem> 
             <listitem>Database Development</listitem> 
        </listofitems> This is the second piece of text: 
         <listofitems> 
             <listitem>Hardware</listitem> 
             <listitem>Software</listitem> 
        </listofitems> This is the final piece of text. 
    </text> 
</content>
```

Those annoying bits of text are, at least, in roughly the correct area and the template should work with any old XML thrown at it.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate template to match text nodes if they are children of the `text` element:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::text]">
```

That way, any other child elements in between do not interfere. Then, write a second template to keep your XSLT processor from outputting text inside of `listitem` elements, too:

```
<xsl:template match="*[parent::text]"/>
```

If you omitted the template match above, the default behaviour of XSLT would lead to any text nodes that are children of `listitem` being output as well.

Note that XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 differ in their treatment of text nodes. One of your approaches:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

Does actually output all text nodes in XSLT 2.0. Below is a stylesheet that works for both 1.0 and 2.0.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="//text">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()[parent::text]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[parent::text]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
This is the first bit of text: This is the second piece of text: This is the final piece of text.
```

---

Alternatively, if you do not need to process the child elements of `text`, add a `select` attribute to `apply-templates`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="//text">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()[parent::text]">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

When this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content/text/text()">
        <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is applied to your input. It outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
    <text>
        <h1>Services</h1>
        <h2>Engineering</h2>
        <span>This is the first bit of text:</span>
        <listofitems>
            <listitem>Database Analysis Tools</listitem>
            <listitem>Website Development</listitem>
            <listitem>Intranet Development</listitem>
            <listitem>Database Development</listitem>
        </listofitems>
        <span>This is the second piece of text:</span>
        <listofitems>
            <listitem>Hardware</listitem>
            <listitem>Software</listitem>
        </listofitems>
        <span>This is the final piece of text.</span>
    </text>
</content>
```

will this solve your problem?

Comment: It's useful, but I can't reference any elements directly by name since this is going to be used to display XML generically. The XML I've used is just an example of what may have to be displayed.

Comment: @stuffedbadger : It is your responsibility to show exactly what kind of output you need and what your _actual_ input XML looks like. Please state this more clearly. Otherwise people might be reluctant to spend time on answers next time.

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I can be than "output the following xml to the browser exactly as it appears below" and "as this is meant to be used with random XML which could be of any format I won't be able to reference nodes directly". My apologies if this was somehow confusing.